# Why do we get different results/outputs on different compilers?

Tags: compiler-construction, primitive-types

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
    double num = 5.2;
    int var = 5;
    printf("%d\t", sizeof(!num));
    printf("%d\t", sizeof(var = 15/2));
    printf("%d", var);
    return 0;
}
```

Running this program on VS 2010 and GCC 4.7.0 gives the output as `1 4 5` and using Turbo 3.0/4.5 gives `2 4 5` as the result.

From where can we get the exact sizes of the datatypes ?

I did read the following links:[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562249/size-of-primitive-data-types), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331751/does-the-size-of-an-int-depend-on-the-compiler-and-or-processor), [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041994/different-compilers-different-output), [link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7209094/why-can-different-c-compilers-give-different-outputs-for-a-c-program) and [link5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/size-of-int-long-etc)
But they were not able to answer my query !

Comment: The standard specifies that sizeof(char) is one.  Beyond that it only specifies the relationship between type sizes so they will be different on different platforms and toolchains.

Comment: How did %d become a char in VS2010/gcc ???

Comment: Neither `char` nor the `%d` are really important to the question you asked.  I was only talking about what is in the standard.  See Oak's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a complicated way to ask why `sizeof(bool)` is 1 in some compilers and 2 in others. And indeed, the C++ standard does not require the size of `bool` to be 1, which means that different compilers may allocate a different size for it, and this is the answer to your question.

As for *why* it doesn't require it to be 1, [take a look at this related question about `sizeof(bool)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067492/why-the-sizeofbool-is-not-defined-to-be-one-by-the-standard-itself).

If you are not clear why `bool` is involved here at all, it's because you invoke the `!` operator on a double value, which is the equivalent of checking if it's non-zero, and such a check returns a `bool`. The other two prints are basically `sizeof(int)` (because `int / int` is an `int` itself) and the value of an integer.